# Restore iTunes Media Keys

Tags: itunes, keyboard, keybindings

Like most, I'm having trouble with my media keys being hijacked, so I can't press Play/Pause/Rewind/Fast Forward and have it work with iTunes. In the past, the culprit has been Google Chrome Music, but this time that's not it. I don't have that extension, or any other media extension installed. I don't use Spotify or Pandora or have any media applications other than iTunes. The fn setting in System Preferences is also not the solution because I don't have it checked.

I'm open to any solution, and am familiar enough with command line if anyone has a really technical solution. Please and thanks in advance!

Comment: It might be worth checking and unchecking it in Preferences anyway... can sometimes fix a corrupt entry in a preference file. Though if your other function keys (e.g. Brightness and Volume) are working as expected without pressing Fn, that would confirm the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @scottishwildcat thanks for the reply! Yeah, I've gone through the preferences a ton of times in the last few days trying to figure it out. I even tried changing shortcuts around and restoring everything to the defaults -- nothing. It's just so weird. The only program I've installed recently is Adobe Premiere, but I've checked and it doesn't even use the media keys...

Comment: Strange... another couple of things to try then: a) do they work if you switch to a different user account? and b) do they work if you uninstall Adobe Premiere again, even though AP doesn't obviously use them?

Comment: @scottishwildcat I figured it out! What's causing it anyway. I switched users like you suggested and the keys were working. And then I discovered my boss gave me a script that install a bunch of programs we use at work, but also disables the keys and only uses them with Rdio. Now I need to figure out how to undo it:

`launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist 2> /dev/null`

Comment: @scottishwildcat Figured it out! I just ran `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted!